# Time-based wallet in Laboratory

Tags: stellar-core, stellar-sdk, stellar-laboratory

I want to build a time-locked token with certain funding target to be used for crowdfunding.

I have found the code for creating time bounds in javascript but I am unable to find the UI of Stellar Laboratory

```
const txOptions = {
        timebounds: {
            minTime: now.plus(60).toNumber(), // 1 min from now
            maxTime: 0,
        },
```

I am unable to find how to define a target value to be reached in a given time for the purposes of crowdfunding.

Comment: I'm providing a platform for timed payments, see here https://smartstellar.org

Answer (score 1):

There's no built-in support for crowd funding targets. You'll have to build it yourself from the various building blocks available -- combinations of onchain transactions, and offchain logic that trigger sthem.

Comment: Can you share any documention